# Excel how to remove selection area name?

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, office-for-mac

So it appears once I created `accounts` it selects a group of cells.
How can I delete `accounts` so it will not select a group of cells anymore.
Please see screenshots:

[image: original]

[image: dropdown menu showing the item i'm trying to delete]

Answer (score 2):

These steps might be slightly different as I'm working from a Windows PC.

You can easily remove this named range by opening the `Name Manager` on the `Formulas` tab. This will give you a list of all the named ranges, delete the one you want to remove.

Comment: It will also change by version.  I'm using Excel 2016 for Mac, and it can be found under Formulas, Define Name

Answer (score 2):

Go to Formulas tab- Define Name- Selet the name you want to remove- selet "-" symbol.

[image]